# Javascript: how to add and remove class of a tag onscroll event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am pretty new to javascript, I have learned some of the basics but don't completely grasp it yet. I am trying to get the color of my nav on the right to change by adding an active class to it depending on what section I am at. I don't quite understand how I would implement appending the class to my nav item when it passes the specific div. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I just placed some random code below just so I can link the codepen. It's alot easier than me posting my entire html/css code here.

HTML

```
div class="global-container">

<div class="logo">
    <div class="layer2">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="copy">
    <p>&copy; text</p>
</div>

<div class="links">
    <a href="#">
        <img src="">
    </a>
    <br>
    <a href="#">
        <img src="">
    </a>
</div>

<!-- End of Logo !-->

<ul class="sidebar">

    <a href="#section1">
        <div class="item">

        </div>
    </a>
    <a href="#section2" >
        <div class="item">

        </div>
    </a>
    <a href="#section3">
        <div class="item">

        </div>
    </a>
    <a href="#section4" >

        <div class="item"  >

        </div>
    </a>
    <a href="#section5" >
        <div class="item">

        </div>
    </a>


</ul>
<!-- Sidebar!-->

<div class="content-container">
    <div id="section1">

        <div class="inner-container">

            <div class="intro-message center">


                    <h1 class="headline-big center">
                    section1</h1>


                    <h2>
                    text
                    </h2>

                    <p>text</p>

                    <div class="button">
                    <a href="#">text</a>
                    <a href="#">text</a>
                    </div>


                    <h6 class="change">text</h6> 


            </div>  


        </div>  

    <div id="section2">



                <div class="about-message">

                    <div class="left">
                        <h1>
                            Section 1</h1>


                            <p> text
                            <br>
                            <br>

                           text</p>
                    </div>


                </div>  

    </div>







    <div id="section3">

        <div class="inner-container">

            <div class="education-message ">


                    <h1 >
                    section3</h1>



        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
                    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>










                    </div>  



            </div>  





        </div>  

    </div>



    <div id="section4">

        <div class="inner-container">

            <div class="intro-message center">


                    <h1 class="headline-big center">
                    Section4</h1>



                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
                    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>




            </div>  





        </div>  




    </div>

    <div id="section5">

        <div class="inner-container">

            <div class="intro-message center">


                    <h1 class="headline-big center">
                    section 5</h1>




                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
                    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>




            </div>  





        </div>
```

CSS - I want to add to .item class

```
.active {
   background-color: red;
 }
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BZzbGz

Heres an example:
https://bonhomme.lol/

The nav-lines on the right change color as you scroll. I want to achieve this effect but the color changes depending on which section div I've reached.

Comment: Don't just insert meaningless code, but the most relevant parts. After all, that's what the check is for.

Comment: Format your code, remove spaces and provide a minimal example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I get the scroll position of the items in the navigation.  Then add/remove the class based on the current scroll position.  Check this out:

[Your modified Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bReJwr?editors=1111)

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

     $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);

     function onScroll(event) {
         var scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop();

         $(".sidebar a").each(function() {
             var currDiv = $(this).find("div");;
             var currLink = $(this);
             var refElement = $(currLink.attr("href"));

             if(refElement.position().top <= scrollPos && refElement.position().top + refElement.height() > scrollPos) 
             {
                 $(".sidebar a div").removeClass("active");
                 currDiv.addClass("active");
             } else {
                 currDiv.removeClass("active");
             }
          });
      }
 });
```

**Edit**: Here's the explanation you requested of the items we're using in the IF

`refElement.position().top` returns how many pixels from the top of the page of that element is.

`refElement.height()` is returns the pixels representing the height of the element.

`scrollPos` returns in pixels how far down on the page we currently are.

Comment: This works exactly as I wanted! Thank you. I was wondering if you could explain the arguments in this function. if(refElement.position().top <= scrollPos && refElement.position().top + refElement.height() > scrollPos)

Comment: Sure.  See the updated answer.  Also, if this solved your problem, please mark it as the right answer and vote it up. :)

Answer (score 0):

For changing class of an element on scroll - jquery:

```
 <script>
  if($(document).scrollTop>10){
  $("#myDiv).addClass("active");
 }
 else{
  $("#myDiv").removeClass("active");
 }
```

Answer (score -2):

You have different options to do this: use a library or write the code yourself. If you chose the latter, you can try the following approaches.

1) Compare offsets

`window.scrollY` gives your the scroll amount of the page. `element.offsetTop` gives you the (fixed) offset of an element on the page. You can compare these values to determine, which element is currently in view.

2) get screen coordinates

`element.getBoundingClientRect()` gives you the screen coordinates of an element. You can use these to check if it is at the top of the page.

Now you just use a hook on the scroll event to check the positions and know where you are at. My code snippet only accounts for scrolling down, I leave the "scroll up" case for you to implement as an exercise.

```js
var headings = [document.querySelector("h1"),document.querySelector("h2"),document.querySelector("h3"),document.querySelector("h4")];
var nav = document.querySelector("nav span");
var currentIndex=0;

document.addEventListener("scroll",function(){
  // get the current position of the element
  let currentElPos = headings[currentIndex].getBoundingClientRect().top;
  // if it's near the top border update the navigation
  if (currentElPos < 100){
    // in your case, you would update the class
    nav.innerHTML = headings[currentIndex].innerHTML;
    if (currentIndex+1<headings.length) currentIndex++;
  }
  
});
```

```css
h1,h2,h3{
  margin-bottom:20em;
}
h4{
  margin-bottom:30em;
}
nav{
  position:fixed;right:20px;top:20px;
  border:2px solid red;padding:5px;
}
```

```html
<nav>You are viewing:<br><span>First heading!</span></nav>
<h1>First heading!</h1>
<h2>Second heading!</h2>
<h3>Third heading!</h3>
<h4>Fourth heading!</h4>
```